# Uploading text file to jFrog artifactory with python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, artifactory

I wrote the falling short code snippet to play around with requests and artifactory. I'm trying to upload a simple text file.

```
import requests

url = "https://myurl.jfrog.io/artifactory"
auth = ("myusername", "mypassword")
file_name = "test.txt"

response = requests.put(url + "/data/" + file_name, auth=auth, data=open(file_name, "rb"))
print(response.status_code)
```

I'm getting error code 405, what am I doing wrong? There are hardly any examples of using requests to work with artifactory

Comment: i found this with a quick google ... maybe helpful https://gist.github.com/pgorsira/ca978d06b90f9019bedb

Comment: This also gives me a 405 error code.

Comment: @OriaGruber see Vijay and my suggestion below.

Answer (score 1):

The specified request seems to be redirected to  https://myurl.jfrog.io/artifactory/data/<file_name> which is not an actual repository within an Artifactory instance.

The 405 response code ("Method Not Allowed") gives a good hint.

Try creating a repository within Artifactory and append it after /artifactory, so it should be :

https://myurl.jfrog.io/artifactory/<repository_key>/data/<file_name>

Please find additional information in the REST API documentation:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-DeployArtifact

Comment: Adding to Tom's answer, Just replace your `url` value with the repository name. Like `url = https://myurl.jfrog.io/artifactory/reponame-generic-local` and it should get you `201`.